# How to make user input call a function C

Tags: c

How can i use a variable(that I would get from user input) to call a function ?

```
char user_function[10];
scanf("%s", user_function);
user_function(); //Calls the function named user_function that the user typed
```

(without having something like this)

```
char user_function[10];
scanf("%s", user_function);
if( strcmp(user_function, 'printf()'))
printf();
```

Comment: if you dont want to use if, use switch

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't.

At some point you have to look at the string contents and use those to call a particular function.

You can "hide it" a bit by doing something like a lookup table/hashmap of strings to function pointers, but in the end it is still just "look at the string and decide what to call"